# error : too few arguments to function?

Tags: c

I did the exact same thing in another part of code and got no error or any problem with it's way of working but in this part and so it gives me an error.
So the function is;

```
void triangle(int height,int base)
{
   printf("Enter the base of the triangle:");
   scanf("%d",&base);
   printf("\nEnter the height of the triangle:");
   scanf("%d",&height);
   int area;
   area = (height*base)/2;
   printf("\nTriangles area is %d.",area);
}
```

I'm using a switch-case function for my code and this is how I call it in main function;

```
case 3:
     {
         triangle(area);
     }
```

Feels weird but this works perfectly;

```
void square(int length)
{
printf("Enter the length of square:");
scanf("%d",&length);
int area;
area = length*length;
printf("\nRectangles area is %d.",area);
}
```

Like this;

```
case 1:
        {
            square(area);
        }
```

Comment: what did you expect to happen ? Your `triangle` function takes two parameters (`height` and `base`), yet you only pass one when calling it (`area`).

Comment: The function wants two parameters and you pass one? Is this the question?

Comment: Look at your function definitions: void square(int length) vs void triangle(int height, int base). You have to supply what is in the brackets when you call the functions.

Comment: Given how you're written the contents of those functions you likely want to use local variables instead of passing parameters.

Comment: **nonetheless**, where are the `break;`s of cases?

Comment: You might as well return the calculated area instead of `void`.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're trying to return the area. Either you'll need to use a pointer to do that or a return int (or other type). int square(){..... return area}. It's probably worth looking up a beginner C tutorial as these are quite newbie questions (which is why you're getting down votes).

Comment: @Pam thanks for the answer,I just understood that I need to use the variables of the function when calling.Not the variable that I want to see as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I did the exact same thing in another part of code and got no error or
>   any problem with it's way of working but in this part and so it gives
>   me an error.

C does not guarantee to diagnose all incorrect code, neither at compile time nor at run time.  Nevertheless, you should turn up your compiler's warning level.  If afterward it anywhere accepts a call to your `triangle()` function with other than exactly two arguments and without emitting at least a warning of some kind, then throw it out and choose a better one.

> So the function is;
>
> ```
> void triangle(int height,int base)
> {
>    printf("Enter the base of the triangle:");
>    scanf("%d",&base);
>    printf("\nEnter the height of the triangle:");
>    scanf("%d",&height);
>    int area;
>    area = (height*base)/2;
>    printf("\nTriangles area is %d.",area);
> }
> ```

Note that your function does not actually use the value provided by the caller for either argument, nor does it in any way return any information to its caller, even if you call it with the correct number of arguments.  If that's what you want then it would be better to declare it to accept *no* arguments, and to call it that way:

```
void triangle(void) {
    int length;
    int height;
    // ...
```

Note that `length` and `height` are now strictly local variables.  You call that variation like so:

```
triangle();
```